# Why repartition is not take effect in huge pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have 10 nodes with 32 cores and 125 g each. I also have a dataframe called oldEmployee with two column employeName and its salary.

```
df = ..    
oldEmployee = df.rdd.map(lambda item:....)
    mySchema = StructType([StructField("EmployeeName", StringType(), True),StructField("Salary", DoubleType(), True),])
    oldEmployeeDF = spark.createDataFrame(oldEmployee, schema = mySchema)
```

Now I have UpdatedEmployee created as follows:

```
d = df.rdd.flatMap(lambda ....)
mySchema = StructType([StructField("EmployeeName", StringType(), True),StructField("salary", DoubleType(), True),])
    NewEmployeeDF = spark.createDataFrame(d, schema = mySchema)
```

Now I merge both dataframes:

```
NewEmployeeDF = NewEmployeeDF.union(oldEmployeeDF)
```

Now I Compute the sum of salary for each employee:

```
NewEmployeeDF.registerTempTable("df_table")
salaryDF = spark.sql("SELECT EmployeeName, round(SUM(salary),2) as salary FROM df_table GROUP BY EmployeeName")
```

My problem comes in the following step, when I want to get the max salary. I do as following:

```
maxSalary = salaryDF.agg({"salary": "max"}).collect()[0][0]
```

This line of code takes more than 6 hours and even it was not finish. In the log file I notice, after executing several times with several parameters, that always the number of partition is set to 400 and the execution arrives at the partition 200/400 and freezing:

```
19/04/22 06:46:27 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 53.0 in stage 37.0 (TID 4288) in 2017303 ms on 172.16.140.175 (executor 41) (199/400)
19/04/22 06:46:37 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 192.0 in stage 37.0 (TID 4427) in 2027473 ms on 172.16.140.254 (executor 1) (200/400)
```

You notice that the time for each task is big (2027473 ~33 minutes), I dont understand why till now

Firstly, the salaryDF is realy huge but how can I solve this issue? Why spark partitions the salaryDF to 400 not 590 as I defined? Thank you your suggestion

Secondly, for huge dataframe, do you think it is better to use 
`coalesce` instead `repartition`?

Note please that the conf variable is defined as follows:

```
conf = (SparkConf()
         #.setMaster("local[*]")
         .setAppName(appName)
         .set("spark.executor.memory", "18g")
         .set('spark.driver.memory', '18g')
         .set('spark.executor.memoryOverhead',"2g")
         .set("spark.network.timeout", "800s")
         #.set("spark.eventLog.enabled", True)
         .set("spark.files.overwrite", "true")
         .set("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "20s")
         .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "1g")
         .set("spark.executor.instances", 59)
         .set("spark.executor.cores", 5)
         .set("spark.driver.cores", 5)
         .set("spark.default.parallelism", 590)# this takes effect only for RDD you must do repartition for dataframe
         )
```

by setting `.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 590)` I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/moudi/main.py", line 778, in <module>
    d= maxSalary.agg({"salary": "max"}).collect()[0][0]# the new added
  File "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 466, in collect
  File "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
  File "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o829.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ShuffleMapStage 37 (collect at /home/tamouze/main.py:778) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 19    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:867)    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:863)    at ...
```

Comment: Try to add `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` option according with your business rule (take a look on https://medium.com/@manuelmourato25/how-spark-dataframe-shuffling-can-hurt-your-partitioning-28d05fdcb6fa). About `coalesce()` vs `repartition()` the difference between reside on the partition creation (coalesce leverages existent partitions instead of create it as repartition command)

Comment: Could you do: `df.explain()` and add to your question?

Comment: @IgorUchôa I added the shuffle.partitions and i get the above exception

Comment: Try to decrease this number (~25). As show in the article, high values can hurt the execution.